Injective immersion of topologically closed manifold is a closed map
By definition, an immersed submanifold is a subset $N \subseteq M$ that is a smooth manifold such that the inclusion map $N \to M$ is a smooth immersion.

Let $N \subseteq M$ be an immersed submanifold such that $N$ is closed in $M$ w.r.t. to the the topology of $M$. Then the inclusion $N \to M$ is a closed map.

This is not entirely trivial since $N$ need not carry the subspace topology of $M$. This appeared in a proof in my Lie groups class and I know almost nothing about smooth manifolds.

Your title question is different from the one you are asking in the body of the question. Also, in the context of subgroups of Lie groups, it is most likely a duplicate (Arens Lemma).

@MoisheKohan I edited the title and still tried to be concise. About Arens Lemma, I couldn't find anything under this name in Lie theory.

No, you did not correct: in the title you are talking about injective immersion but in the body of the question injectivity assumption is missing. See my answer here.

And, as stated, the claim written in your post is simply wrong even for injective maps to the plane.

@MoisheKohan Ah, I'm sorry. In my definition (Lee), immersed submanifolds are the images of injective immersions. I'll add this.

See for instance, here.

But the definition that you wrote (of an immersed manifold) makes no sense. You should re-read what Lee wrote and edit accordingly.
